# Sequelize not logging sql queries

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working with sequelize + nodejs + express.

I'm trying to debug my sql queries but can't see them on console.

**sequelize: ^5.21.2**

I tried following:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host: config.host,
    dialect: config.dialect,
    pool: {
        max: config.POOL.MAX,
        min: config.POOL.MIN
    },
    logging: function(str) {
        console.log(str);
    }
});
```

And

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    logging: console.log,
    host: config.host,
    dialect: config.dialect,
    pool: {
        max: config.POOL.MAX,
        min: config.POOL.MIN
    }
});
```

And

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    logging: true,
    host: config.host,
    dialect: config.dialect,
    pool: {
        max: config.POOL.MAX,
        min: config.POOL.MIN
    }
});
```

But all of them simply prints:

```
{}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How did you execute your SQL?

Comment: Standard sequelize functions like findOne

Comment: try adding console.log to the query itself:
Company.findOne({logging: (str) => console.log(str), where:...}).then()

Comment: I just use logging: true and it works

Comment: :(, can you send me the version of sequelize you are using @Fernando?

Comment: It works both V4.4.2 but tested in V5.21.5, in both scenarios work, true or false here's one of my configurations: let sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 1000
    },
    dialectOptions: {
      timezone: 'Etc/GMT-4',
      collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
    },
    logging: process.env.IS_LOCAL ? true : false
  }
);